# What URL path to use to connect to Spring WebSocket using JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I have the following method in a java file:

```
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addHandler(myWebSocketHandler(), "/endpoint")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```

I want to use a JavaScript client to connect to this websocket uri, but I do not know what that uri should be. I dried the following URI:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://"+document.location.hostname +":8443"+"/endpoint");
```

(the 8443 port is the proc on my server for secure WebSockets).

BUT that URI doesn't connect to the websocket. So what is the correct URI

(P.S. the client (JavaScript) connects and immediately disconnects with that URI).

Comment: "connects and immediately disconnects" - do you mean `GET` request is successful, but upgrade to websocket is not? And did you try `DEBUG` log for spring server side? What does it say?